# Basis for the Quotient Topology

Tags: general-topology, quotient-spaces

I was studying some basic topology and was wondering about the basis for a quotient topology. I came up with the following, but I can't seem to find something this elementary stated explicitly anywhere, and [this set of notes](http://math.umn.edu/~sglasman/5345hf16/5345h0921.pdf) *(link is 404, only available in Google cache)* seems to suggest that a <del>the</del> *(fix: Brian)* basis is in general unclear. Have I made a mistake somewhere?

**Lemma**: Let $q: X\rightarrow X/{\sim}$ be a quotient map, and let $\mathcal{B}$ be a basis for the original topology $\tau$ on $X$. Then $q(\mathcal{B})=\{q(B)\mid B\in\mathcal{B}\}$ is a basis for the quotient topology $\tau_q$ iff $q$ is an open map.

**Proof**: Suppose $q(\mathcal{B})$ is a basis for $(X/{\sim}, \tau_q)$. Therefore, the image of each $B\in\mathcal{B}$ is open, and since every open $O\subseteq X$ is a union of the basis elements (and $q(\emptyset)=\emptyset$), $q(O)$ is open. Thus $q$ is an open map.

Suppose $q$ is open. $q$ is surjective, so $q(\mathcal{B})$ covers $X/{\sim}$ since $\mathcal{B}$ covers $X$. Now, consider the intersection $O':=q(B)\cap q(B')$. It is open, since $q$ is open. Thus $O:=q^{-1}(q(B)\cap q(B'))$ is open as $q$ is continuous. Since $q$ is surjective, $O'=q(q^{-1}(O'))=q(O)=\bigcup_{\delta}q(B_{\delta})$ as $O$ is a union of some basis elements $B_{\delta}$. So for all $x\in O', x\in q(B_{\delta})\subseteq O'$ for some $\delta$. Thus $q(\mathcal{B})$ is a basis. By the same construction, any open set in $\tau_q$ is expressible as a union of basis elements, and conversely any union of basis elements is in $\tau_q$. Thus $q(\mathcal{B})$ is indeed a basis for $\tau_q$. $\blacksquare$

Edit: I just realized this certainly does not solve for the general case, derp. It still seems quite useful to not appear though. For instance, the typical question of the quotient of $\mathbb{R}^2$ by $(x,y)\sim(a,b)\Leftrightarrow x^2+y^2=a^2+b^2$ can be seen to be an open map, since every 'open box' in $\mathbb{R}^2$ maps to open intervals in $[0,\infty)$, so the intervals $[0, x)$ and $(a, b)$ with $a$ positive form a basis.

Comment: There are a couple of minor infelicities in the write-up, but you’ve made no mistake. However, it *is* an error to speak of *the* base for a topology: topologies have more than one base.

Comment: Did I do that? Thanks for catching it.

Comment: link is a 404 BTW

Comment: @HennoBrandsma The page seems to have disappeared, it is currently still available from [Google's cache](http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:J8jOmzwSgU8J:math.umn.edu/~sglasman/5345hf16/5345h0921.pdf+&cd=4&hl=en&ct=clnk&gl=us&client=firefox-b-ab), not sure how long it will be there though. The sentence I am talking about is on page 3 (search for 'basis')

Comment: The quotient topology on $X/\sim$ is defined to be the strongest topology  on $X/\sim$ such that $q$ is continuous . So it is equal to $\{q(t):t\in \tau\}$ and $q$ is an open map.

Comment: @user254665 Not all quotient maps are open, for example, the equivalence relation $0 \sim 2$ on the topology $X=\{0, 1, 2\}$ with $\tau=\{\emptyset,\{0\},\{1,2\},X\}$ does not induce an open map, as the open sets in $X/{\sim}=\{[0], [1]\}$ are $\tau_q=\{\emptyset,X/{\sim}\}$. Then $q(\{0\})=\{[0]\}$ which is not open.

Comment: reading the notes, I don't see how your lemma appears useful there. It just uses the definition, no more. And in this example, the quotient map is not even open, but closed and not open.

Comment: In your example with $X=\{0,1,2\}$ we have $q(X)=\{ \{0,2\},\{1\}\}.$ The members of $q(X)$ are not even members of $X.$  How do wish to define the topology on $q(X)$?

Comment: @user254665 The quotient map $q$ sends $x\in X$ to the equivalence class $[x]\in X/{\sim}$, so the members of $q(X)\,(=X/{\sim})$ are necessarily not members of $X$ (since they are equivalence classes of elements in $X$. I believe the quotient topology $\tau_q$ on $X/{\sim}$ is then defined by $\tau_q:=\{U\subseteq X/{\sim}\,|\, q^{-1}(U)\in\tau\}$, i.e. all subsets of $X/{\sim}$ whose preimage is open in $X$. In the example in my comment the non-trivial proper subsets of $X/{\sim}$ are $\{[0]\},\{[1]\}$ and neither of those have open preimages so the quotient topology is the trivial topology.

Comment: @HennoBrandsma I didn't actually really read the notes, I was just using it as a source that says that in general finding a basis for the quotient topology is hard (which it probably is), and I wasn't trying to apply the lemma there. I'm not exactly sure which example you are referring to though, could you be more specific?

Comment: See Engelking, General Topology, chapter 2, first paragraph of section 2.4 for a def'n of quotient topology.

Comment: @user254665 Engelking, definition of quotient topology: "... denote by $X/E$ the set of all equivalence classes of $E$ and by $q$ the mapping of $X$ to $X/E$ assigning the point $x\in X$ the equivalence class $[x]\in X/E$. ... in the class of all topologies on $X/E$ that make $q$ continuous there exists the finest one: this is the family of all sets $U$ such that $q^{-1}(U)$ is open in $X$." Both our definitions (construction from inverse mapping, and characterization by finest topology) are equivalent, but your construction ($\tau_q=q(\tau)$) is wrong as it has too many open sets.