# On the basis for quotient topology

Tags: general-topology

There is some discussion on this topic already in [Basis for the Quotient Topology](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2082488/basis-for-the-quotient-topology). But I had some other questions.

If I start with a basis $\mathcal{B}$  in the original topological space X and consider the basis $q(\mathcal{B})$ in the quotient topology, does it have the following property?

Pick some $[x]\in X/\sim$. Then
$$\exists B \in \mathcal{B} \quad| \quad[x]\in q(B)\implies q^{-1}([x])\subset B$$

Intuitively speaking, I want to know if whole equivalence classes fit into basis elements in this situation.

I think it should be, otherwise I run into some well-definedness issues. But I am not able to prove it in a clean way.

Comment: @Gae.S. thanks, just corrected the error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not necessarily: consider $X=\{0,1\}$, the basis $\mathcal B=\{\{0\},\{1\}\}$ and the open quotient map $q:X\to \{0\}$, $q(x)=0$.

Comment: Ah, this clears things up